# How to make cursor stay in the center of edittext

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have a normal edittext like this :

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/et_word"
    android:ems="12"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

How can I make the cursor stay always in the center of edittext? No matter if user enters something or not. Thanks.

Comment: Provide android:gravity attribute as "center"

Comment: you need set padding left calculate its from device width

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the following code

```
android:gravity="center"
```

This makes sure that your text will always be entered in the center of the `EditText`. By default its value is `left`.

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/et_word"
        android:ems="12"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

Comment: No no it works, I was editing another xml.. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
<EditText 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="start" 
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="Some hint text"
></EditText>
```

Answer (score 1):

please Try adding the following code

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="start" 
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/et_word"
        android:ems="12"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you can add to property in xml file to gravity center then you can get cursor center

```
<EditText
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/et_word"
android:ems="12"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

That can be write from center also.